# dateutil.parser.parse.timestamp gives an older date a bigger integer number

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, python-dateutil, datetime-parsing

I have a bit of a python code that gives me something I really don't understand. Here is my bit of code.

```
fe=datetime.strptime(b, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
fecha=dateutil.parser.parse(fe).timestamp()
```

Where `b` is a string in american/british format with the month before the day, something like `04/19/2017`, and the first line returns the same date like `10/04/2017`, and then the second line of code returns a number.

What I don't understand, at all, is why the date for 10<sup>th</sup> is bigger than for 19<sup>th</sup>. For day 10 I get `1507068000.0` whereas for day 19 I get `1492552800.0`.

Am I missing something? I thought it was a conversion so more recent dates had a bigger number than older ones.

Answer (score 1):

The default for `parse` is `dayfirst=False`. If you set `dayfirst=True` then the timestamps will be correctly ordered.

```
>>> parse('19/04/2017').timestamp()
1492574400.0
>>> parse('10/04/2017').timestamp()
1507089600.0
>>> parse('19/04/2017', dayfirst=True).timestamp()
1492574400.0
>>> parse('10/04/2017', dayfirst=True).timestamp()
1491796800.0
```